# How to get rid of black stripes in the bottom and top of screen in full screen mode

Tags: macvim

When I'm opening macvim in full screen mode I have black stripes in bottom and top. So I can't see some part of code.
[image]

In none full screen there're no black stripes.
[image]

Is there a way to get rid of these stripes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this post that seems to address that problem.

[Full screen MacVim on OS X Yosemite](http://shorts.jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2014/full-screen-macvim-on-yosemite/)

```
$ defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMNativeFullScreen 0
```

Great, it worked !! thanks for confirming for others to find and use.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.